# Returning a binary tree horizontally in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree

How would you return a binary search tree horizontally in a list? Is it possible recursively?

[image]

Expected List : 8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13

[EDIT] I managed to do it in an array thanks to indexes because we know the left son of node i will be 2i+1 and the right node will be 2i+2. I have no clue how to do it with a list though.

Comment: Breadth-first search

Comment: Do you have a particular programming language in mind?

Comment: Well I am currently working with C#

Comment: Why do you think it should be recursively? Since the implementation requires `Queue`, there is no any benefit of using a recursion (actually it only adds overhead and looks ugly - look at the accepted answer)

Comment: I guess I was just curious to see if there was a way of doing it recursively without a queue but I guess you just can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a breath-first search. In pseudocode:

```
BreadthFirstSearch(Node root):

    create empty list L
    create empty queue Q

    Q.enqueue(root)

    while Q is not empty:
        current = Q.dequeue()

        L.append(current)
        if current.left is not null:
            Q.enqueue(current.left)
        if current.right is not null:
            Q.enqueue(current.right)

    return L
```

Or, to do it recursively

```
BreadthFirstSearch(Queue Q, List L):
    if Q is empty:
        return

    current = Q.dequeue()
    L.append(current)

    if current.left is not null:
        Q.enqueue(current.left)
    if current.right is not null:
        Q.enqueue(current.right)

    BreadthFirstSearch(Q, L)
```

With the second approach, you would call it something like this:

```
ConvertBSTToList(Node root):
    create empty queue Q
    create empty list L

    Q.enqueue(root)
    BreadthFirstSearch(Q,L)

    return L
```

Comment: Ok That's a great first step, but do you think about a recursive way of doing it?

Comment: @V.Leymarie added the recursive example

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do a depth first search and record the level for each node, then in the result, use LINQ query

`DisplayNodeVert(Node8).OrderBy(n=>n.Level).Select(n=>n.Content)`

Comment: Would work if node are carrying out their respective level, which is kinda uncommon for most of the binary tree node implementations.